# How to add nominal values to the font-size of all elements?

Tags: css

I was using a specific font family on my website (Cairo) and everything was good till I changed it to another one (Scheherazade), for bad... the new font was small and not good enough to be presented, however, using it is mandatory.

I'm trying to scale the font sizes on my website for all elements at once by adding value to it, for example:

The default `h1` `font-size` is 32px, what I'm trying to do is to keep the original/default value of `font-size` as it is but adding to it 10px.

As a much easier solution, I tried to `zoom` the body but, the result was not as expected since it scales the entire page.

Comment: Font sizes set in `px` [are not scalable](https://andy-carter.com/blog/using-scalable-css-units-for-font-sizes). You'll have to update your CSS.

Comment: Assume it is already united by "em", the question still the same. how to dynamically add 1em on the original value.

Comment: "United"? No, the question is not the same. You cannot add arbitrary numeric values to font sizes. You can scale them proportionately if you're using scalable elements.

Comment: Maybe this is an opportunity to do some housekeeping on your CSS. A well-organized stylesheet should only have a handful of font size declarations anyway.

Comment: BTW, this isn't "scaling". This is increasing. Not the same. Scaling involves applying a coefficient as a multiplier.